# Why does linear motion not affect the reading on a hall probe?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electricity, magnetic-fields, electrons

Moving the hall probe forward at velocity v would make all the electrons in it propel at velocity v, so the magnetic force on each electron (qV x B ) would increase. If so, unless there's some fuzzy stuff involving special relativity happening, shouldn't the reading change?

Comment: The drift velocity is the velocity of the electrons relative to the lattice ions.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that the force due to the magnetic field = q(v x B), so if v increases, that's the equivalent of a higher drift velocity.

Comment: @Farcher Could you take a look at it now?